# Helm install is --values values.yaml explicitly required?

Tags: kubernetes, helm

Using Helm version 2, I was under the assumption that explicitly setting `--values values.yaml` in `helm --name elasticsearch install ./` is **not** required *(i.e. defaults to `--values values.yaml`)*. However I am not seeing this behavior, when I run `--debug --dry-run` I don't see my custom values defined in `values.yaml` being used.

**EDIT:** The only thing that may explain what's happening is `values.yaml` is all namespaced under:

```
elasticsearch:
  replicas: 3
  # ... rest of values
```

The namespacing under `elasticsearch` is required though.

Comment: I don't know where you got the impression that helm (of any version) ever _implicitly_ added `--values values.yaml`; do you have a documentation link that backs up that claim? Because otherwise, the answer to your question is a resounding yes, `--values` is always required to use values from a file (and can be specified multiple times for additive value setting)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit this question? When you just install chart it will use default values.yaml from chart. If you set -f values.yaml you will overwrite default values. Issue is when you are using `--debug --dry-run` you are getting default chart values instead of your own?

Comment: When using `helm --name elasticsearch install ./` it is not using the values defined in the root directory name `values.yaml`. However when I explicitly set `helm install --name elasticsearch --values values.yaml ./` it works as expected.

Comment: Are you using Helm 2.16 or 2.14? I tried to do what you mentioned on Helm 2.16.7 and without specyfing `--values values.yaml` it deployed my changes. Also those changes were visible whe I used `--debug --dry-run`. Any specific steps to reproduce?